How to export useContext in a page.tsx file?
This causes an error when deploying to vercel export const [weight] = React.useContext(Context); I have narrowed it down to the fact that export default function Home() also uses export and for some reason anything else export on the page just breaks this.
Here is the error code from vercel: app/page.tsx Type error: Page "app/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page. "Context" is not a valid Page export field.
Please note that the code works perfectly with npm run dev this error only appears to fail the deployment.
Cheers
I have tried to run the context without exporting, but this causes a lot more issues to be fixed unfortunately.

Why is useContext outside a functional component. Can you show more of your code and what are you doing

When you practice folder based routing make sure the respective page.tsx files having the default Page() function as export default function Page() { }

Probably Vercel is refusing to accept Context on a router. Move that field  into a dedicated provider; i.e. ContextProvider.ts
